# Transfer a row of data from one object to another

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

My goal is to transfer a row of data from one object to another, where `selected_city_codes` would state which items to remove from `airport_data_2` to `airport_data_1` by using `city_id`

Not sure how to approach appending the data from `airport_data_2` to `airport_data_1` but I illustrated my result to removing the row from `airport_data_2`.

Is there a more efficient way to transfer data between two object?

```
airport_data_1 = [{"departure_time":"12:00","arrival_time":"03:00","city_id":"BOS"},  
{"departure_time" :"12:00","arrival_time":"03:00","city_id":"BOS"},
{"departure_time" :"01:00","arrival_time":"04:00","city_id":"SFO"},
{"departure_time" :"03:00","arrival_time":"05:00","city_id":"BOS"},
{"departure_time" :"03:00","arrival_time":"05:00","city_id":"SFO"}]; 


airport_data_2 = [{"departure_time" :"03:00","arrival_time":"05:00","city_id":"DEN"},
{"departure_time" :"04:00","arrival_time":"06:00","city_id":"SJC"},
{"departure_time" :"04:00","arrival_time":"06:00","city_id":"JFK"},
{"departure_time" :"06:00","arrival_time":"09:00","city_id":"SJC"}]; 


selected_city_codes = ['SJC','JFK']; //items to remove from `airport_data_2` to `airport_data_1`

//my attempt to remove the listed values from selected_city_codes
for(i in selected_city_codes) { 
    airport_data_2 = airport_data_2.filter(item => item.city_id != selected_city_codes[i]);
}
```

Result Before

```
airport_data_1 = [{"departure_time":"12:00","arrival_time":"03:00","city_id":"BOS"},  
{"departure_time" :"12:00","arrival_time":"03:00","city_id":"BOS"},
{"departure_time" :"01:00","arrival_time":"04:00","city_id":"SFO"},
{"departure_time" :"03:00","arrival_time":"05:00","city_id":"BOS"},
{"departure_time" :"03:00","arrival_time":"05:00","city_id":"SFO"}]; 


airport_data_2 = [{"departure_time" :"03:00","arrival_time":"05:00","city_id":"DEN"},
{"departure_time" :"04:00","arrival_time":"06:00","city_id":"SJC"},
{"departure_time" :"04:00","arrival_time":"06:00","city_id":"JFK"},
{"departure_time" :"06:00","arrival_time":"09:00","city_id":"SJC"}];
```

Result After -- our desired result

```
airport_data_1 = [{"departure_time":"12:00","arrival_time":"03:00","city_id":"BOS"},  
{"departure_time" :"12:00","arrival_time":"03:00","city_id":"BOS"},
{"departure_time" :"01:00","arrival_time":"04:00","city_id":"SFO"},
{"departure_time" :"03:00","arrival_time":"05:00","city_id":"BOS"},
{"departure_time" :"03:00","arrival_time":"05:00","city_id":"SFO"},
{"departure_time" :"04:00","arrival_time":"06:00","city_id":"SJC"},
{"departure_time" :"04:00","arrival_time":"06:00","city_id":"JFK"},
{"departure_time" :"06:00","arrival_time":"09:00","city_id":"SJC"}];

airport_data_2 = [{"departure_time" :"03:00","arrival_time":"05:00","city_id":"DEN"}];
```

Comment: You can loop over `airport_data_2` and use `if else` to create a two new arrays. One will be a new  `airport_data_2`, the second will be used for `concat()` with `airport_data_2`. But I doubt it have significant performance effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a slight change to your implementation and added the ones that are equal.

```js
airport_data_1 = [{"departure_time":"12:00","arrival_time":"03:00","city_id":"BOS"},  
{"departure_time" :"12:00","arrival_time":"03:00","city_id":"BOS"},
{"departure_time" :"01:00","arrival_time":"04:00","city_id":"SFO"},
{"departure_time" :"03:00","arrival_time":"05:00","city_id":"BOS"},
{"departure_time" :"03:00","arrival_time":"05:00","city_id":"SFO"}]; 


airport_data_2 = [{"departure_time" :"03:00","arrival_time":"05:00","city_id":"DEN"},
{"departure_time" :"04:00","arrival_time":"06:00","city_id":"SJC"},
{"departure_time" :"04:00","arrival_time":"06:00","city_id":"JFK"},
{"departure_time" :"06:00","arrival_time":"09:00","city_id":"SJC"}]; 

selected_city_codes = ['SJC','JFK']; 

for(i in selected_city_codes) { 
    airport_data_2 = airport_data_2.filter((item) =>{ 
        if (item.city_id === selected_city_codes[i]){
        airport_data_1.push(item);
      }
      return item.city_id !== selected_city_codes[i]
    });
}

console.log(airport_data_1)
console.log(airport_data_2)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```